# Account suspended for 1 year? Is this correct?

Tags: support, account-suspension

I stumbled upon an answer by a particular user. Since it had 3 upvotes, I wondered what's wrong, because the user has only 1 reputation.

Going to his profile, I saw that the account is suspended. Reading more, I found out that there's a [1 day penalty box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

However, the account information says

> The suspension period ends on Mar 13 '15 at 5:31.

That's not a 1 day penalty box, it's a 1 year penalty box. Is there something I missed or is it a bug in calculation of the suspensed time?

Comment: Suspensions can be arbitrarily long. There's even a high-rep user who's suspended until 2025. I won't mention who it is for obvious privacy reasons.

Comment: This is answered by [How long can a temporary suspension be?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211217) but of course that's now on Meta.SE, so I can't vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: It makes you wonder why SE thinks that the user will come back in 11 years. Or even 1 year.

Comment: @bjb568 Those are probably meant to be permanent. When a user is so disruptive that you need to simply get rid of him/her - forever.

Comment: @Mystical Well, that is obvious. But why do they have to call it a "suspension" and make an arbitrary future date it they could just ban?

Comment: @all: Ok, and we can't simply delete the user, because this has a massive impact on reputation?

Comment: The account isn't summarily deleted because Jeff's philosophy is to hope that a user can and will reform.

Comment: @Thomas Reputation of SE? What?

Comment: @bjb568: No, as far as I know all upvotes of a deleted user will be reverted. So with 2400 upvotes, there's 24000 overall reputation points lost (distributed among different users).

Comment: @Thomas Yes, that's by-design. If a user was so horrible that you ban them (or want them to never return by suspending them for 11 years), their votes probably won't be high quality.

Comment: Number of votes cast will not prevent a user from being deleted, @ThomasW.

Comment: If you don't suspend such a user and instead delete, they'll just keep coming back with new accounts. This specific user did this anyway, but at least now there is a suspended account to merge the evasion accounts into. Note that such a user doesn't *start* with a 11 year suspension! It starts with days, then escalates from there as the user fails to reform. Eventually the moderators ran out of patience and you end up with a suspension that is effectively indefinite.

Comment: And that user *does* come back from time to time to check their account, I guess because they still use Stack Overflow for answers; I've seen the 'visited' indicator update.

Comment: It's maybe not a good idea to discuss this in public. Imagine, you are the user and you are publicly shamed.  There is a reason the suspension message is only visible on the user profile.

Comment: @bjb568 It's not unheard of for a user to return after one year. It has happened. :)

Comment: Suspensions are now capped at 1 year as of ... uh... a few months ago. But we didn't go back and adjust any of the extremely long-term suspensions that were already in the system.

Comment: So I [found](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251212/suspension-till-2027) suspension till 2027. Wow!

Comment: @nicael: Are you sure it is the right link?

Comment: We may not know the century. It could be year 2127 or 2227. One limit [mentioned previously is 274 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284807/account-temporarily-suspended-network-wide-for-the-next-10-years-and-cannot#comment1059459_284807). (100,000 days = approx. 274 years. (Or 99,999 days?))

Comment: If it was once a four-digit limit in an input field, 9999 and the epoch was 2000 ('00) (not relative to the time of suspension), it would fit with this century: 9999/365.25 = 27 years 137.25 days (Julian years)

Comment: @Peter apparently not... :) the correct link seems to be https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251212/suspension-till-2027

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A user's initial suspension will be short — usually a week — but subsequent suspensions (especially for the same problem) will have increased length.

An in-depth writeup on this topic has been provided by Tim Post at [How long can a temporary suspension be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211217/how-long-can-a-temporary-suspension-be) on Meta.SE.

As he says there, the details of any particular user's suspension are private, aside from the general cause and end date.

For completeness, even though you already seem to know this: while an account is suspended,  its rep is set to 1. The removed rep is given back after the suspension expires.

Comment: I *completely* forgot writing that. Thank you for linking it or I might not have noticed it and wrote it all over again.

Comment: Google never forgets, @TimPost. Upload your mind!

Comment: Is there a limit on the maximum age of an user?

Comment: (2^64)-1, @devnull, naturally. 18 quintillion years ought to be enough for anybody.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Nah!  You can't be born prior to `Jan 1, 1920` for registering on SO.  I wouldn't have been able to, if I was born a day earlier.

Comment: That's just your birthday, @devnull; you can still have been alive for more than 94 years. You have to think fourth-dimensionally.

Comment: __Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:

  - Birthday must be after 1920/01/01__

Comment: @Pops: Why "obsolete"? The pseudo-suspension of underage users doesn't happen? Or you just mean it's not relevant to this here question?

Comment: @JoshCaswell It doesn't happen anymore. According to people with law degrees, we actually have to remove the accounts entirely; suspension is insufficient. (Plus it kinda reveals their birthdates.)