# Suspension till 2027

Tags: discussion, support, account-suspension

> This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The
>   suspension period ends on Feb 1 '27 at 19:59.

Er... What?! Till 1 february 2027?!
This is [user2398036](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2398036/user2398036).

> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the
>   complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in
>   timed suspension for anywhere from 1 to 365 days.

It is a *bit* more than 365 days.

Comment: I don't have privileges for that, but maybe the user's only question revisions might give a hint.

Comment: Definitely gives a good hint, yes @nKn. [Especially this one](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16630713/16)

Comment: @nKn Why do you think you don't have the privilege to view the revisions?

Comment: @Stijn I suspect nKn meant that he doesn't have privileges to see more specific information.

Comment: @Stijn I have, I meant extended moderation privileges.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1357/

Comment: The funny part is that with that amount of downvotes, they basically achieved what he wanted.

Comment: >ok i got my answers, we can delete this post now, i am not helping google users.

http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3a91cd62-0384-4c7c-8d14-e4a047874778/view-source
lol

Comment: @RobertHarvey Nice coincedence that today's comic is so relevant :)

Comment: He gets a silver badge for a notable question!

Comment: Clearly he was suspended by at least 14 mods and the sentence is being served consecutively.

Comment: Mark your calenders for 12 years in the future! We must check when he edits his post again.

Comment: Will the user receive his original reputation score and everything after the suspension period over? (OR) He will start again from scratch (with reputation score 1)?

Comment: @Rahul He will start from his original reputation, but I doubt if he will have any by that time)))

Comment: @Keavon 27-14=13 )))

Comment: @nicael Wolfram|Alpha: "12 years 9 months 13 days 10 hours 36 minutes 43 seconds in the future" I rounded down.

Comment: `+50` and `-110` ohh my god.. I think he has more friends.

Comment: massively low downvotes can attract sympathy votes (which defeat the purpose of downvoting because the user gets net positive rep)

Comment: I'm surprised nobody mentioned a very likely situation: sock puppet ring.

Comment: Willl Internet or StackOverflow ever exist in 2027? I really hope so!

Comment: Wow. What a huge tool for asking a question, then selfishly deleting the content so nobody else could benefit from it. I HOPE he stays banned until 2027

Comment: @Muz I would imagine that a lot of those upvotes were given merely for the hilarity of the whole thing.

Comment: I upvoted only for the hilarity of the whole thing.

Comment: @nKn, which question was it? Theres no question listed at http://stackoverflow.com/users/2398036/user2398036

Comment: @Pac http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630713/is-it-true-that-in-python-you-can-import-specific-functions-from-a-module-unlike

Comment: Dont know why but it seems like Jail Period for him ,and he will come out of it on Feb 27.

Comment: Well, and I thought that that user 1083704 which is suspended until May 11 '24 holds the record. No doubt that it re-defines the term "temporarily".

Comment: We may not know the century. It could [actually be 2227](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284807/account-temporarily-suspended-network-wide-for-the-next-10-years-and-cannot#comment1059459_284807), not 2027 (though it does not fit exactly with the maximum of about 274 years (99,999 days) and (2227-2014)*365.255 = approx. 78,000 days ((2127-2014)*365.255 = approx. 41,000 days)).

Comment: More than half way through their suspension period now

Comment: OK, it is actually this century (and this decade). The other example was about 2 1/2 century more (2292-03-18)

Comment: They [removed the ambiguity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284807/account-temporarily-suspended-network-wide-for-the-next-10-years-and-cannot#comment1253614_284807) in 2022.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Beyond what it says on the profile, we don't share that information publicly <strike>unless the user themselves were to come here and specifically broach that subject</strike>.

I can assure you, though; that suspension was *wholly justified*.

*EDIT*: [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/447356/shadow-wizard) notes in a [comment below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251212/suspension-till-2027/251213?noredirect=1#comment5076_251213) that this is no longer possible for the user to bring up the topic here, on the 'new' Meta Stack Overflow, as it's now a normal per-site meta. The user would have to go to the new Meta Stack Exchange for that ability, though I don't know if it's appropriate there, nor is it often productive, anyway. Contacting the team directly is usually better, IMO.

---

Moderators don't do suspensions that long now. Generally speaking, a suspension of that length would have only been done in the past for extreme situations involving repeated, significant infractions.

Since then, we actually are limited to one-year suspensions. Something that would suggest a longer period would really suggest a need for more strict measures. There were informational tracking uses for these very long suspensions before, but they are not needed so much anymore due to additional information being tracked on deleted/destroyed accounts.

---

[Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) noted in the comments below that you may sometimes still see a user with a network-wide suspensions longer than the 365-day limit; network-wide suspensions can not be done by moderators, but must be done by Employees, such as Community Managers. I'll quote his comment:

> FWIW, you may occasionally still see extremely long suspensions on accounts that are suspended network-wide. There are generally extremely good reasons for those, and they tend to involve users who've already been deleted and came back anyway.

Comment: Just because this part is public, and easily accessible from the user's page, see the history on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16630713/revisions. Yeah, I'd ban him too.

Comment: FWIW, you may occasionally still see extremely long suspensions on accounts that are suspended network-wide. There are generally extremely good reasons for those, and they tend to involve users who've already been deleted and came back anyway.

Comment: I understand life imprisonment and I get only one life. But I can make any number of email addresses and hence, accounts. Does 13 years, even make sense?

Comment: @TJ-, creating a new account is nothing but starting afresh. all his work of accumulating reputation and privs are gone. So, won't even make much sense if he does so.

Comment: What if he comes back after 2027-02-01? What if he still waiting and waiting and WAITING??

Comment: @totymedli - Maybe by then he'll have had an epiphany that his way of giving back to the world was by asking questions and that by deleting his question, he's not hurting Google but others like himself. Of course, the irony would be if three 20k users went and deleted the question since it's scored so low.

Comment: "unless the user themselves were to come here and specifically broach that subject" - but it's not possible, as the user is suspended and this is now per-site meta, so he can't post or comment here.

Comment: @Rahul More like accumulating hatred and downvotes.  Starting over is probably a more attractive option, even if he just comes back to be a nuisance.

Comment: @Rahul Which "work of accumulating reputation" are you referring to in this special case?

Comment: @glglgl, I mean his accumulated reputation before he made this hatred/disputed comment over his post. Not sure, if he is total nuisense from scratch.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I actually wasn't aware that suspensions on the normal sites also extended to the relevant Meta site (since my primary activity had always just been SO and Meta.SO). Hmmm...

Comment: @AndrewBarber per-site meta yep, MSE of course is a standalone site and now this MSO is just like any other per-site meta. I guess you can ask the user via mod messages (I believe users can reply to them?) if it's OK to share details about the suspension.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, they can always reply to those. But we pretty much would never do that. We'd prefer to keep the details private, and won't tend to initiate anything to do otherwise. It would only be because the user themselves made it public that we would respond.

Comment: Fair enough, @Andrew. Curiosity is a dangerous thing anyway! ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Especially to cats, I hear. Luckily, they have a few extra lives.

Comment: Ohhh, for some reason it reminded me of Alley Cat. What a strike of nostalgia! http://www.80sdos.com/screens/alleycat4.png

Comment: I don't get it. StackOverflow won't even be around anymore by 2027. Why not just delete the account, it's easier and actually an equivalent measure.

Comment: @RaduMurzea I alluded to that in my answer; at the time we did that, there were tracking reasons for it. We don't really need to do that anymore, but it's not a big deal for us to go through and delete those old ones now. Haven't deleted the one being noted here so that it remains for context of this question. If I'd happened upon it otherwise, I'd have deleted it.

Comment: @RaduMurzea depending on the system, deleting the user might delete his content and some of that you might want to keep. So better to lock down the account and delete (or make inaccessible to other users) the content that is the cause for the ban.

Comment: @jwenting Actually, the delete/destroy process takes those things into account. Up-voted questions with answers, for example, won't tend to get deleted. The exact details of what does/does not get deleted vary between delete/destroy, with destroy being a bit more harsh. But basically, we don't take the undeleted content into account there. Finally, we can also manually un-delete anything that looks worthwhile but gets auto-deleted.

Comment: @AndrewBarber was talking generally, not specifically about SE.

Comment: @jwenting Oh; that works differently on other sites?

Comment: @AndrewBarber never underestimate the power of on delete cascade :)

Comment: @cupcake Ack!!! :)

Comment: Oh wait. The question was finally deleted. Maybe undelete it?