# Wrong explanation about why can't I edit locked post

Tags: discussion, bug, edits, locked-posts

I opened my old locked post [Suspension till 2027](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251212/suspension-till-2027) and hovered my mouse above "edit" button. Just was interested, what alt text would appear. And saw:

> Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites

It looks very confusing because:

- not the reason why I can't edit locked post
- I am not suggesting edits on my posts, I am editing them
- I can already edit posts instantly

Comment: I believe the system is designed in such a way, anytime a user tries to make an edit and does not have full edit privileges on the post, it assumes it is a suggested edit.  I ran into this once before in an entirely different context: [Uninformative (and Confusing) Error Message for Suggested Edit Conflict](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195410/uninformative-and-confusing-error-message-for-suggested-edit-conflict)

Comment: @psubsee2003: But as OP mentions he does have full editing privileges. Unless you meant "tries to make an edit on a post that isn't accepting edits".

Comment: @BoltClock Understood.  I was just pointing out the likely design.  Like I said in the question I linked, the message is wrong and confusing, so it should be changed.