# Reason for not letting me edit a meta post

Tags: support, bug, edits, migration, locked-posts

I came across [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302303/1048572) via the *Hot Meta Posts* box and upon reading it, I thought it could benefit from an actual link to the [linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) tag that was discussed, so I went to the edit button as always.
However, the edit link is greyed out, with the following title text:

> Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.

What gives?

Upon googling, I found [this 2011 post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97371/183280) by @Jeff Atwood, stating that there are no edits on meta sites. This seems to be severely outdated however, clearly [I can edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi?tab=activity&sort=revisions) lots of meta posts. Also, I was not trying to *suggest* and edit, I wanted to *make* one.

For some reason the post is [**locked**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/302303/revisions) by [Community♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), but there is no notice of that on the post itself (other than *comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews*) - there only is a migration notice and a close banner.

So, three questions:

- Why is there no locking banner on the question,
- and why was it locked automatically in the first place?
- Can you please fix the [wrong explanation about why can't I edit locked post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256185/1048572)?

Comment: I think it's locked because it failed migration from SO. You can still edit it [over there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31951147/3001761).

Comment: See when it got locked: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/302303/timeline

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver for pointing me to that post! While the question isn't an exact dupe, the answer clears up the process.

Comment: @Rizier123: Yeah, the same information is available in the revision history, what threw me off is that it got locked *before* it was closed (even if the timestamps are the same), despite the causality being the other way round.

Comment: @bergi no problem.  I just figured the answer there would give you all you needed to know on what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I've gotta learn to read (or get some coffee):

> migration rejected …
>   …*votes, comments, and answers are locked due to the question being closed here.*

Looks like I didn't really understand what happened here (partially because I couldn't believe that it was "migrated back" despite being clearly meta); also Community's action seemed somewhat unrelated to the close-down that happened after the lock in the revision history.

[Animusion's explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292227/1048572) of the process is great, even if there are some quirks; and obviously [the edit button title text is still wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256185/1048572) but that's a separate issue (please upvote it!).

Comment: Maybe you are interested in my FR [Don't treat closed questions on meta as rejected migrations from main](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299599/dont-treat-closed-questions-on-meta-as-rejected-migrations-from-main)

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yes, definitely +1 to that. Thanks!