# Trying to edit a locked post results in an incorrect tooltip: "Suggested edit queue is full"

Tags: bug, status-review, locked-posts, tooltips

[image: Screenshot of a deleted, locked answer showing a misleading tooltip about the Suggested Edit Review Queue being full]

I have editing privileges, so I think the tooltip should say "Locked posts cannot be edited" or something like that.

Comment: I just wonder ... what do you want to edit there? :P

Comment: I can live with that wrong message, to be honest. There are more important things to fix...

Comment: I wonder if this is because there's a "can user edit" check and if it's "no" the check re the queue state gets checked before the "post is locked" check.

Comment: Fairly sure it always use to say "edits cannot be made on locked posts" or similar

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256185/wrong-explanation-about-why-cant-i-edit-locked-post?rq=1#comment28683_256185) :D

Comment: All edits on locked posts (regardless of user reputation) have to go through an imaginary suggested edit queue. Unfortunately this queue has a capacity of 0, making it kind of hard to find times when the queue isn't full.

Comment: @zoe I checked with some people in SOCVR and they weren't able to reproduce this problem, though they said that it had still been an issue earlier this week. Do you have some reason to think it's still occurring? You should be able to edit since mods have the ability to do so.

Comment: @Catija I status-review'd because I got confirmation from another user (<10k, on a locked, public post). Just asked them to check again, and it's suddenly fine? Seems like it's an inconsistent bug, but I don't have much details here. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465849/using-ioc-for-unit-testing/70703527#70703527 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101203/understanding-why-we-use-inversion-of-control-containers-for-unit-testing/70703371#70703371 (unrelated to the initial confirmation, but same error message).

Comment: It seems to be a semi-rare and definitely obscure bug, but it's still periodically reproducible. That said, I suspect it may only be a problem when the edit queue is full, and that that's why it's not currently possible to reproduce. Might need to wait until it fills up again to test, but I'm not sure. The current theory I have is that there's a bad condition that checks if the queue is full regardless of rep or post ownership, prior to other checks (like the one for locks), and that it therefore produces a bad message. haven't checked the code to verify, admittedly

Comment: @Catija Can confirm, I asked Zoe about it (read: groaned about the unhelpful error message) on the 8th at 19:48 GMT. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/935aH.png)'s the error while trying to click the edit button on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70570020/3270037). I am now instead getting "Post is locked." I'll try again when the queue is bigger.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, @Zoe Thanks for the added context. I'll ask the devs to look at the order of checks and ensure that if locked, we only ever say something to the effect of "this post can't be edited because it's locked", regardless of whether the s.e. queue is full, which is irrelevant. :)

Comment: Similar issue? MSE: [Attempting to edit a Merged question shows wrong error: "Suggested edit queue is full"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353839/281934)

Comment: @pkamb Looks like the same thing

Comment: Good catch, @pkamb  - I'll make a note to respond to your post once we figure this out.

Comment: @Catija As I said I'd check again later, here is said update: It is currently saying "Suggested edit queue is full", queue size is reported to me as 385 (although I gather whether or not it is currently "full" is cached and recalculated less frequently): https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrQYG.jpg