# "There are too many pending edits" on a locked post

Tags: bug, edits, error-message, locked-posts

I tried to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11635/4284627) to remove the "best way" phrasing to make it less opinion-based, but when I try to do so I got this error:

> [image: There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.]
>
> There are [too many pending edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84362/349538) on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.

The error message should be about the post being locked and not about the number of pending edits.

This problem can be reproduced, but only when the suggested edit queue is full.

As an aside, this question is locked for being a community effort, so I think it should be allowed to edit it and vote on it, but that's already been asked for [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346955/349538) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341606/349538).

Comment: @yivi I get that error message too now. It probably depends on how many pending edits there are, maybe there are fewer pending edits now than when I tried an hour ago.

Comment: This was [already reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350564/6083675), but it was so long ago that the message changed. Duplicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to edit a locked post results in an incorrect tooltip: "Suggested edit queue is full"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350564/trying-to-edit-a-locked-post-results-in-an-incorrect-tooltip-suggested-edit-qu)

Comment: This shouldn't be closed as "can no longer be reproduced", because it can be reproduced only when the suggested edit queue is full (I wouldn't disagree with closing it as a duplicate though).

Comment: @yivi Are you sure it's full right now? If I try to edit a non-locked post as a logged out user it works, which means that the queue is not full.

Comment: @yivi I got the error message again just now, maybe you could try again. Also, when you say you get no "Improve this post" link, do you mean on the locked question or on another post? Because the locked question has no "Improve this post" link anyway. And the number on the /review page is cached so it's not always accurate.

Comment: Logically, I tried on a non-locked post. But now I was able to reproduce the issue on your question. Might be related to the state of the suggested edit queue. https://cln.sh/KKZ4TN5JthFdnhCpzcwy