# Editing a locked answer gives the wrong error message

Tags: bug, answers, locked-posts

I tried to edit [this locked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64639647) and got an error:

> There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.

However, that seems to be the wrong error, even if it is a true statement. I think the correct error is that the post is locked and may not be edited. (I wonder if the error conditions are tested in the wrong order).

### Update

It looks like the error message is now correct, but I think that there is still a subtle bug - I assume the size of the edit queue has gone down, so this message no longer triggers. In fact even if the edit queue is maxed out, we should still not see the pending edits error in this case.

Comment: Also reported recently here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427609/there-are-too-many-pending-edits-on-a-locked-post

Comment: Thank @yivi, that second one is closer. I wonder if this is too trivial to be worth fixing.

Comment: @halfer Considering that the queue is almost always full here, they really should fix one problem or the other.