# Consequences of Failing audits, and rejected edits

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, rejected-edits

I Occasionally fail review audits, and have been blocked for a day or so due to bad behavior as well. (I am still learning. . .). I wanted to know what (if any) are the long term impacts of failed audits, disputed, denied flags, and rejected edits.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251212/suspension-till-2027) to scare you, even though it won't ever happen to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no long term effects if you learn from your mistakes and improve over time. If you continue failing audits, it will lead to longer bans from /review. Some bans are automatically applied by a script, but moderators can apply bans manually as well. We don't like to disclose the details, because in the latter case we treat each case separately. Also, if we give out a detailed set of guidelines, some may be tempted to see how close to the line they can stay without really improving.

Comment: Bill, can you talk about declined flags as well, since it's also part of the OP's question? I think I might have seen claims that having declined flags reduces the priority of future flags? Or the number of flags you have available? I can't remember the details, but I thought there might be something. Or maybe that was part of what you did not want to disclose? :)

Comment: @RetoKoradi Your flags can gain and lose priority, but I'm not sure of the details. I think this is one of the things kept secret so people don't try to game it. Even moderators don't know for sure, as far as I know.

Comment: Is the flag priority thing true on all sites, or just SO/Bigger sites? I've been looking to try and find that lately, since I'm far more active with flagging over on Arqade. (I don't have enough of a feel here to flag more than I have yet.)

Comment: @Kendra I'm not sure. I know it's not only SO, but I've only ever seen evidence of it on other bigger sites on the network.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'll keep looking then. It's not huge deal (I've only got one declined flag on Arqade so I'm not in a rush to find out) I just wanted to know. I'm sure somewhere on the network is a list or something, or somewhere deeper in the depths of Arqade meta. :)