# What would the approximate dollar value of a point of reputation be if a market existed?

Tags: discussion, reputation

We've seen estimates put on the value of a Facebook "like". So, what's 1 point of SO reputation "worth"? If you could buy/sell it, what would be the exchange rate to USD?

Why would reputation have real-life value? The main reason I can think of is it could be used to help find employment. If that's true, then an estimate of "value" should be determinable (although wildly variable).

#### Note: I am not advocating buying/selling reputation: This is an intellectual exercise only!

---

Don't know why this is getting punished - perhaps a sacrilegious concept?

Just FYI, I think it could be given a dollar value, although:

- It wouldn't be very much (less than 1 cent per point)
- There is no way to find out (or at least there should be no way)

Comment: How much is your time worth?

Comment: Confirmed: micro-transactions coming to SO.

Comment: @TZHX, Ayyyy the horror ! 50 points only $0.99, now available via inapp purchase !

Comment: Well. http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#work-compensation-so (and no, you don't need to tell me this doesn't answer the question about absolute dollar value - that's why it's a comment and not an answer).

Comment: Not sure why all the downvotes, this seems to be a perfectly acceptable exercise.

Comment: Hmm, if I find out that an interviewer only spent one second looking at the number instead of 10 minutes reading a sampling of my posts then that will be a quick "thank you, goodbye".  Clearly he's just looking for meat.

Comment: Dollar value? Half a unicoin, give or take.

Comment: @J.Steen See [Good subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).  Having subjectivity is different from being primarily opinion based.

Comment: Actually never mind. I'm in too good a mood to get into a subjectivity argument on meta.

Comment: @J.Steen Honestly, I'm not really commenting on this specific question (I just don't care enough) I'm mostly just saying that it's not inherently contradictory to close a discussion as "primarily opinion based".  They aren't *inherently* immune from being closed for that reason.

Comment: "If you could buy/sell it, what would be the exchange rate to USD?" the minute you can buy or sell reputation is the minute is stops being worth anything - surely that's obvious?

Comment: "There is no way to find out (or at least there should be no way)" So.... how are we supposed to answer the question? You just said there is no answer. And since it isn't answerable, I downvoted.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET As per original question - it's an intellectual exercise. Although it is very opinion based - perhaps that's why it's getting nuked.

Comment: ELEVENTY BILLION SPACE DOLLARS!!!

Comment: @Bohemian Even as an intellectual exercise, I don't see how we can calculate an incalculable number....

Comment: Only 1 cent per point? You are kidding I think. I wouldn't sell for less than 10$ per point.

Comment: It's worth however much other people are willing to pay for it. The higher the price, the longer it could take to find a buyer, if ever. For example, [this guy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270795/is-it-legitimate-to-buy-stack-overflow-reputation) thought it was worth like 25 cents per point.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think you can actually *measure* reputation converting it into dollars (or any other currency).

Every day, people work on Stack Overflow to help their fellow programmers solving any kind of problem and coding any kind of program: let's just assume that 1 rep point is considered equal to 1$ (the value is not important at all). Then try to figure out what would this mean:

- If I ask a question seeking for help, and get a bunch of upvotes because my question is well-written and has founded reasons, then I'll earn hundreds of dollars out of nothing. Would that make sense? Earning (hypothetical) money because of being unable to solve some problem? It does look pretty ridiculous.
- If I answer a question and my answer gets downvoted even though I provided a reasonable answer (maybe because there's a better solution), I'll then start to lose money for my work: like paying to do my work (for which I should be paid instead).
- It may happen for an answer showing minimum effort to get strongly upvoted, causing an enormous profit to the answerer, although there hasn't been any effort at all.
- It also may happen for an answer showing a good amount of effort and research to get highly downvoted because of other reasons: the answerer will lose reputation (so, hypothetically, money), would this make sense? I don't think so.
- Members of the community will start arguing for the most silly reasons, because **money changes everything**.
- Bounty questions? That would become a pure massacre.

These are the most important reasons I could think of, but the list is obviously longer and longer than this.

So, basically: **I don't think you could be able to approximate a (fair) monetary value for reputation points at all**.

Comment: It's not ridiculous to say that questions are worth something: upvotes come (over time) because you have provided a clear and _findable_ expression of a problem that someone else had, which led her to the solution.