# What to do when suspecting user of giving away or share their SO account with other people?

Tags: discussion, accounts

I couldn't find anything when I searched and I got curious since I know it happens:

Is it allowed to give away your account or share it with someone else?

Given the connection to the career pages, it feels like your SO account should be personal, but people sell/give away/share accounts with reputation so that a person can get the reputation without needing to ask good question or have skills to answer, which nowadays can be very hard things to do given the amount of completion on beginner level questions.

If it isn't allowed, what do you do when you suspect that to be the case?
Or worse, that an inactive user has been hijacked?

Comment: Very related: [Is it legitimate to “buy” Stack Overflow reputation?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270795/is-it-legitimate-to-buy-stack-overflow-reputation)

Comment: Consider a situation where someone answers a question using your profile, then a recruiter reaches you, you go to the interview and they see you have no idea on that topic.

Comment: Thank you, while it doesn't focus on the sharing or free part, it is related in answers. I've seen cases where siblings or close friends share the accounts as well as those who either bought the accounts or paid someone to use it.

Comment: "very hard things to do given the amount of completion on beginner level questions" Then compete on hard questions ? I assume flagging a post for mods attention and explaining the situation is the way to go.

Comment: My SOP is if I suspect some type of fraud then I mod flag and explain what I think is wrong.  Even if there is no fraud I think the mods tend to mark them as helpful as its always better to have them double check then let fraud go.

Comment: I rarely notice it in posts, it's usually conveyed in chats when a user with a lot of rep suddenly can't understand the very basics of a language they've previously answered questions on effortlessly.

I would like an answer focusing on the "what do you do" part when you suspect someone of this.

Comment: I edited it to be more relevant to the question of what to do

Comment: From [This meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133244/selling-stack-overflow-accounts) it is not allowed. So mod flag if you're concerned by the problem ;)

Comment: @Tensibai but what if it's not one question on SO that is revealing it?

Comment: Very few would admit to it when asked directly, even in chat.

Comment: @Gemtastic flag any of their post. When you have a concern with one user, flag any post of this user with "Need Moderator Attention" and describe the problem as precisely as possible in the text box. (turning this in an answer, it's too long for a comment)

Comment: The question and related links seem to focus on **selling** reputation, or other forms of dishonesty. I'm sure that **some people simply don't care**. They may answer a few questions, gain rep, and then pass their login to a colleague or friend or even "publish" their credentials in some way, because they simply don't care about ~"these ridiculous unicorn-internet-points". Of course, it is not desirable, and undermines the idea of **rep==trust** that is occasionally proposed. But if someone with such an account does "Bad Things®", he will be punished regardless of the original account owner.

Comment: [A (suspected) recent case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420316/this-suspension-was-not-fair-since-my-friend-didnt-want-to-merge-3-accounts-for#comment926329_420316) (it is probably going to be automatically deleted).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the allowability, see [Selling Stack Overflow accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133244/selling-stack-overflow-accounts) on the mother meta.

For what I would do (assuming starting in chat per your comments):

1. Get some links to older chat message from the user (if any)
2. Get some links to new messages from the user (they never disappear, there's a history when you click on the arrow next to the message)
3. Randomly choose a post from the user (a good one would be showcasing the change seen in chat)
4. Flag for Moderator Attention and explain your concern. Give the links to chat so the moderator can get a closer look on what raise your concern.

Obviously the same can be done if the user start posting questions he should be able to answer himself.