# Show cases when my review differs from the community consensus

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

When I click on <kbd>my review history</kbd> in, for example, [Low Quality Posts Review History](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) (bottom right corner), I would like to see reviews where my opinion was different from the community consensus.

For example for [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8120042) community consensus was *delete* (and I voted for deletion) so I would see nothing special, but users *Apul Gupta* and *MathieuF* voted <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> so they would see something like: [image: disputed] next to the review (or some better-worded brief-description).

I think this would help aligning views inside the community on what's "*right*" in disputable cases and help people improve.

Comment: I like the idea of knowing more readily in a way, but I think it won't affect those who don't care, and it'd demotivate (in-your-face "you're wrong") those actually trying to improve. Definitely should't be on the public profile. 99.9+% of my "disputed" are where  I was right and the rest of the world was wrong. As I was getting used to the system, there were so many bad reviewers on edits, that this would actually have been no help except to give me lists to rollback edits on :-)

Comment: "99.9+% of my "disputed" are where I was right and the rest of the world was wrong."  So true.  Take that, statistics!

Comment: To put it another way, I don't believe the sum of reviews in general represents what the (active) community believes is "right", just what the mass of reviewers at the time guessed at.

Comment: @davidism stats for cases like that would still be useful - for example, one could use these to learn how to comment on reviewed posts to make other reviewers support their evaluation

Comment: @gnat I totally agree, it just reminded me of "60% of the time it works every time". :)

Comment: Cross-site dupe of [Adding the consensus to review's history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248338), which has a userscript to implement this.

Comment: I would love this.  I am always going back through my review to see how I reviewed against my peers.  I seam to get a lot of disputed flags coming out of the triage and suggested edits.

Comment: @BillWoodger I agree that it shouldn't be part of "public profile"... for example I vote "Looks OK" for *really* bad answers (and occasionally down vote them) and I would like to know what's the community consensus on such reviews...

Comment: Consider @NathanTuggy's link above, maybe there's a userscript (I won't pretend any indepth knowledge of what that means) that does something close to what you want.

Comment: @BillWoodger: Chrome (and perhaps other browsers) have native support for local JavaScript executed on webpages as a sort of lightweight addon: a userscript. Firefox and most other browsers have addons designed to host very similar scripts (and indeed Firefox's Greasemonkey was the reference implementation for the concept in the first place); most userscripts are cross-compatible between essentially all implementations.

Comment: Vyktor, good quesiton! I asked this question a few weeks ago and I got downvoted -10. Everyone was asking "why do you care to know why they got deleted, etc?"

Comment: @JaredBurrows I can't match your comment to this question. Why what was deleted? Do you have a link for your question?

Comment: @BillWoodger I deleted my question once it hit -10.

Answer (score 3):

Alastair Reynolds adresses this in his science fiction novel [*The Prefect*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/89195.The_Prefect). In short, the titular character is a *moderator* for the democratic Right To Vote. In the system described in the novel, everyone is allowed and even encouraged to vote, and it is illegal to take away voting rights of individuals.

Fraudulent behavior of a sub-community is gravely punished with a total "lockdown" - cessation of all communication with that community for a while, possibly as long as 100 years. Individuals trying to ring the system can be punished to death (that's a step too far for SO).<sup>1</sup>

Now here comes the trick. All voting is done per computer, and the software is intelligent enough to recognize who voted along with the consensus, and who against. Even more so, it *also* recognizes those who voted *against* the consensus but turned out to be Right After All.

Since it is not allowed by law to diminish an individual's voting rights, it cannot do anything about the Stupid Masses (there always seems to be one: in real life, here on SO, and a thousand years in the future - what a depressing thought). But it **can** assign a slightly higher weight to voters who seem to take the broader/better/long term view.<sup>2</sup>

It would be similar in purpose and use as the Dupe Hammer. The [original proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865) suggested

> [..] I think it would make sense to allow users with a gold tag badge to have a 3x weight for close votes in those tags.
>   Please keep in mind, this isn't suggesting full moderator one click closure. It only adds weight to the vote. A single user could not do it on their own.

which was implemented as Mighty Mjolnir, giving its wielder the equivalent of a weight of 5 Close Votes:

> [..] You can **instantly close** as a duplicate any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
>   (*answer to that proposal, my emph.*)

It reminds me of

> "[..] a being we call the Quadruple. [..] But the Quad has never revealed himself to any other citizen. Perhaps he fears a public stoning. His own wisdom must be a wonderful and terrifying gift, like the curse of Cassandra."
>   (*The Prefect*, Alistair Reynolds, p. 122)

and so I strongly suggest to implement it ever so slightly more subtle. Edit reviewers that do not accept a review *and* it gets rejected may gain a tenth or so in weight. As voting is not as crucial as in the novel, you can even consider disadvantaging  *approvers* for finally-rejected edits (and the reverse).

I do not propose weighing the vote of "bad" reviewers all the way down to 0, essentially taking away their right to vote:

> "[..] The system keeps monitoring those individuals, constantly tuning the appropriate weighting factor. If they keep on voting shrewdly, then their
>   weighting remains, or even increases. If they show a sustained streak of bad judgement, the system weights them back down to the default value."
>   "Why not just remove their voting rights entirely, if they're that bad?"
>   "Because then we wouldn't be a democracy," Thory replied. "Everyone deserves a chance to mend their ways."
>   (idem, p. 122)

The only thing is, the system of the novel has 100 million voters, and since it's a democracy, Majority rules. Raising the number of votes for edit reviews (and Close and Reopen posts, possibly?) to truly democratic values would grind the entire system down to a halt.

Still, it may be worth a go.

---

<sup>1</sup> Common suspensions on SO "to cool down" are typically one week. Bad Behavior is punished with a year-long suspension, but may be way (*waaaa-a-a-yy*) longer [under special circumstances](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251212/2564301).

> I can assure you, though; that suspension was *wholly justified*.

I'm totally convinced.

<sup>2</sup> This is the topic of another question: [Rejected Edit that Formatted Code to be Visible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296759/2564301), which is an excellent example of the subtility that may be necessary.

On first glance, the consensus seemed to be the editor made a bad call, which should reflect on his status. However, it turns out *the consensus was wrong* and so the editor should be redeemed, the voting weight of the four Nay-voters decreased, and the one That Got It Right All Along increased.

(Also related: [Is an edit which transforms a wall of text appropriate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296765/2564301))