# Rejected Edit that Formatted Code to be Visible

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, rejected-edits

I had [an edit rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8375364), where I was mostly formatting the post so that the code would appear as code. Some of it wasn't even showing as visible before my edit. (One piece of code just appeared as a dash before my edit)

The edit was rejected for this reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must  make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Which I was surprised by, I had thought that the original post should have all this missing code formatted properly and separated neatly with linebreaks for readability. It seemed to not make sense without it (though I'm not that familiar with HTML so I may be mistaken and have been accidentally destructive).

I am confused that there was total consensus. So if it is a case of poor judgement or carelessness on the reviewer's part, then it's a bad coincidence.

All three people did reject it, and not even a Reject and Edit where they performed the formatting correctly. But then later [you can see](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30728369/revisions) that the original poster edited it in and someone else proceeded to tidy it up like I had attempted (though our edits are far from identical).

Did I make the wrong call and if so what did I misunderstand?

Comment: "_Did I make the wrong call_" No. You see, At first glance, I saw that you've added extra code (from the rendered output). This explains why the reviewers rejected your edit. Honestly, I would've rejected it too. I think that you should've used a better edit summary.

Comment: There wasn't total consensus, the first reviewer approved it. The three others should have, too... You could have improved also the rest of the question, but still, your edit was clearly good.

Comment: @CoolGuy That makes sense now that I look at it. I intended the 'Fixed formatting' in my summary to mean that the post's code was formatted into view but that was a very unclear way to mark that.

Comment: Some reviewers just don't know what the heck they are doing. That more often means approving than rejecting where the opposite would have been right though. There's a reason we get served both rendered output and raw markdown.

Comment: @CoolGuy if someone suggests such an edit and it seems that a bunch of code has been added, the least a reviewer could do before just rejecting it, is to switch to the Markdown view.... which shows perfectly where the code came from

Comment: There wasn't actually total consensus. It was reviewed by 4 people, and 1 moron Accepted it.

Comment: @TZHX: [this older question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294705/2564301), which popped up on my screen unexpectedly, may be of your (and others') interest. +0.1 for you, I'd say. (Oh wait, it didn't "pop up", I  read it because Nathan found it.)

Comment: "Some reviewers just don't know what the heck they are doing." yes, what he said. ( @Deduplicator )

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you click on the link you provided and would be too lazy to switch to the markdown TAB it looks as if a lot of text was added in that was not there.

Unfortunately there are a lot of reviewers that are too quick to reject, without, if something seems amiss with an edit, first double checking that the error might be on their side.

Switching to markdown view would have shown that you essentially only added white space, and if they had done so, I cannot see a reason for rejecting your suggested edit.

Comment: @TZHX Had not noticed you were the one to approve ;-) Unfortunately it looks like reviewing is a team sport and the others on your team did not pay as much attention as you did. Unfortunately you cannot choose the team members, fortunately your not stuck with the same team all the time.  Maybe you can post about gaming on Suggest Edit, and then I'll try and do my best to come up with an answer that includes some English idiom I don't fully understand.

Comment: I always sucked at team sports.

Comment: @TZHX I would just blame the others. WRT reviewers, it would be nice to get feedback  on reviews where there was no consensus e.g. in the [history](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) maybe your "team-members" could learn from that (assuming they would put in the effort to go back and look).

Comment: @Anthon I know there is a request out there to show in your review history if your review matched the consensus but I am having trouble finding right now.

Comment: Found it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294705/show-cases-when-my-review-differs-from-the-community-consensus

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the link, saves me the effort writing something up. But the comments are not that encouraging. I might take a look at the userscript mentioned, in one of the comment. but it would be good for all to be able to see where there was no consensus.

Comment: It used to be (before I gave up  on edit reviews) that if I did not reject within seconds, two people would approve regardless of how bad the edit it.

Answer (score 4):

Your edit summary was inaccurate.  That means reviewers saw a pile of new code added, with the summary "Fixed formatting, couldn't follow English to improve it."

You should have said "a lot of code was hidden by formatting errors.  Fixed formatting, so it appears again.  English was so bad I couldn't follow it."

Here, instead of just "fixed formatting", it describes what the format fix did.  Reviewers seeing that might pause before rejecting, and check the raw version of both sides.

If your edit isn't clearly valid from the rendered output, explain why it is valid in the edit description.  In practice, expecting reviewers to look at the raw post will just get you rejected.

Your post looked more like an audit they where supposed to reject (with piles of seemingly unrelated code injected) than an audit they where supposed to accept.

Comment: Come on, even without switching to markdown it is quite clear that the code was coming from the question, as you can see bits of it in the rendered view. Especially because that looks like an audit, one should be doubly careful when reviewing it. Justifying bad reviewing practices by saying that the summary was inaccurate is not the way to go...

Comment: @nico the OP asked what they did wrong.  They cannot make reviewers better: they can make their good edits handle the reviewers they get.  The reviewer behavior is dictated by the audit system and the carrots, which award robo review, so if your edits are not good for robo review, they will get rejected more than they "should" in some perfect world.