# Is an edit which transforms a wall of text appropriate?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I got an [edit rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8344827) which I personally find very useful since it turns a good answer with a too-prosaic writing into one which is better readable.

Despite my explicit intent to preserve the author's style as much as possible, the edit got rejected.

Is the style of editing against the SO spirit?

Comment: Thank you for editing! (Yes, it *is* appreciated.) Your use of bolding entire sentences had me worried but fortunately that's not something you did habitually in other edits. It is almost never necessary to do that (and if there are other things in a post that irk me, I take it out as well). ... I can't help noticing that you missed out a few obvious ones in [this earlier edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8247091).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You lost a word while editing.  This sentence should have `ListView` at the end:

> We know that inside ScrollView we cannot use another scrollview like

Apart from that, I think this is a great edit. I would have approved and improved it to add the missing word, but I can see how the rejection reason chosen by the reviewers is valid.

Comment: approve and edit to get the missing word back in would indeed be the right solution. That were 3 lazy reviewers and 2 not paying attention.

Comment: @Anthon: I'd say the edit was more useful than the single missing word. I also doubt it was rejected because of that, but rather the reviewers saw too much red and green and didn't read the changes.

Comment: I indeed missed the word. Submitted a new edit and it got accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15243964/revisions

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy That might well be. It is Friday, people are in a hurry to get home for the weekend.

Comment: As for _why_ it was rejected, I've though of a few explanations.  The rendered output differences _appear_ to be alarmingly different.  But if you looked at the markdown differences, it becomes obvious that most of the content was preserved while noisy stuff like "Thanks" and "Hope this solution help you very much." were culled.  I'm guessing the reviewers rushed and didn't read your edit comment or investigate past an initial impression.

Comment: Missing a word is not a valid reason for rejection in this edit. It's just a terrible excuse. They most likely wanted 1 quick review and to move on.

Comment: @Anthon: "*It is Friday, people are in a hurry to get home for the weekend.*" – then they shouldn't be giving themselves additional (not actual) work to do, and just go home instead.

Comment: @DavidThomas Agreed but that would delay them obtaining a review related badge.

Answer (score 12):

Your edit was basically okay. To add to the existing answer, I'd like to point out that many reviewers are basically lazy idiots, who will reject an edit like this because it ends up affecting a vast majority of the post ... *without actually reading it*. Unavoidable fact of life, alas.