# Review Triage: is there a way to follow skipped questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Every now and then I check the [Triage Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/) but I'm not sure how to deal with some of the questions so I skip them.

However, it kills me that I didn't find the right way to handle the question, so besides pondering over what I should've done, is there a way to follow the question and see what other reviewers opted for?

Comment: You can either open the question in a new tab before voting to skip, or you can press the back button in your browser.

Comment: Something better than that? To be able to shut down the pc and when coming back to check the list

Comment: Open in a new browser then star the Q?

Comment: I think these suggestions are actually backing up the fact that there is no convenient way to do it (I shouldn't have to open new tabs, check browser history, etc.)

Comment: @Adelin Your browser doesn't have a bookmark/favorite feature?

Comment: @Servy what do you think?

Comment: @Adelin Apparently it doesn't, since you needed to ask how to keep track of a link until later.  Since you don't have a browser with a functioning bookmark feature, I'd suggest trying to get a new browser that *does* have it.

Comment: @Servy A link? Singular?

Comment: @Adelin I'm not aware of any browser's bookmarking feature set that can only keep track of one link, and not multiple.

Comment: @Servy I expected more from a user with you rep points

Comment: I can say the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to your review history, and check "show skipped reviews".

You will find it on the review page, on the "history" tab at the corner on your right hand.

[image]

Then scroll to the bottom right of the page and click on this link:

[image]

Alternatively, you can click on this direct link:

**https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history?skipped=true&userId=0**

<sup>*Note that the userId parameter seems to be required (doesn't matter what value) for users with 10k+ rep due to having a different default history tab displaying recent reviews from everyone</sup>

However, I warn against using other's Triage review as guidance; the quality of Triage reviews has been discussed a lot here.

Comment: Where do I find the review history?

Comment: The URL needs to have the userId parameter as well.

Comment: @SurajRao Would the SOCVR be a good place to ask for discussing one's Triage reviews? I'd like to give the OP an alternative to looking at other people's Triage reviews.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Only when you're not logged in, it seems. I can use that link when logged in, and it takes me straight to my review history. When not logged in, however, it gives me a 404.

Comment: @SurajRao that path leads to the list of reviews that were *not* skipped, contrary to what I'm looking for

Comment: @S.L.Barth Does it? It seems that for me (I'm logged in), it has the same effect as https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history

Comment: @SamuelLiew Ah, maybe we're talking past each other. You want to see the OP's review history, not your own? Then it needs the UserID.

Comment: @S.L.Barth sure.. people are welcome to ask a query regarding a review.. Anyone who is online in the room would respond.

Comment: [The triage history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history?skipped=true) combined with [this suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294705/show-cases-when-my-review-differs-from-the-community-consensus) is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @S.L.Barth I meant that `https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history?skipped=true` does not take me to my own review history, and I still need to scroll to the bottom of the page to click on the "my review history" link (which contains the userId parameter). You are saying this link directly works for you?

Comment: @SamuelLiew - for me too (without user ID). Probably you have some extra privilege

Comment: @SamuelLiew Yes, it works for me. Firefox 57.0 on Windows.

Comment: @SamuelLiew - We, puny humans, don't have [access to the mod tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: I found a workaround and have edited into your answer. @Adelin 10k mod tools shouldn't affect viewing of personal review history

Comment: @SamuelLiew That link works for me too. Seems a bug that, apparently, some people need to add a userID.

Comment: @SamuelLiew [As per the link I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools): *The full history of reviews by all users in any /review queue.* - this is why you need to add user ID and I don't.

Comment: @Adelin That makes sense now. Good to know :)