# How do you report an underage user to Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, users

Today I came across a question that had been self-vandalized by the original poster. When I then a took a look at the user's profile, I saw that it said that the user was just **11 years old**. The age field on the profile said 13 years, but of course that's probably because the minimum required age for participation on any Stack Exchange site is 13.

How do I report this underage user, and what happens to their accounts when they're reported?

Comment: It's important to note that our minimum required age is a direct consequence of the [Children's Online Privacy Protection Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children's_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act) (COPPA).

Comment: I saw this user as well; e wasn't off to a good start.

Comment: This should be a [meta-tag:faq-proposed] on [meta.se]

Comment: If he asks a good question-  answer it.  If he doesn't-  treat the question just like you would for an adult.  Who cares what his age is?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to report him?

Comment: +1. Since there is no private messages on here, I don't think there's any risk for abuse or other nasty stuff, so why delete the account ? He'll just create a new one right away.

Comment: @AndréDaniel: It's not about abuse on *this site* (although there's still chat and such); it's about the *law* that SE is enforcing.  As for the reason behind a deletion, that's something you would have to ask them.

Comment: This is a simple matter of law @AndréDaniel. COPPA to be precise. Allowing users below the age of 13 to participate requires an administrative effort that's simply not worth it. And it as a result leaves SE with no other option than to nuke those accounts where users are under the age of 13. The potential of danger for an underage user really isn't important here.

Comment: @user3580294: I don't believe SO users are responsible for ensuring that two unrelated parties follow the laws of a different country.

Comment: Pretty sure the law doesn't require you to report under-age users to SE. Personally, I think it's a dumb law, and I certainly wouldn't report any under-age user I saw.

Comment: No, *you* aren't required to report it, but if you don't there is potential for SE to get into legal trouble. Which would you prefer?

Comment: @tmyklebu The issue might be that SO operates in the US, and so has to follow the laws of the US despite the locations of its users. I'm not a lawyer, though...

Comment: @Seth: You're not a lawyer, are you?

Comment: @tmyklebu Actually nvm. Think I understand what you're talking about...

Comment: If the user creates an account, he admits being over 13. Whether that's true or not isn't SE's problem and SE can't really verify it, so we should give the benefit of the doubt and keep the account.

Comment: @AndréDaniel if he however then goes on to explicitly state that he's younger (which has happened in the past, in fact a user was pretty vocal about that for a long time) the only option is "bye bye account". Heck, you could try it for yourself, but I'd highly advice against it if you value your account.

Comment: @user3580294: Sure.  But people outside the US aren't bound by US law.  And there's no reason for the community to participate in enforcing US law.  *And* I don't think there's a requirement that SE vets every single user who uses your website for 13-ness.  If they happen to discover someone's under 13, they have to wipe out their traces.  (IANAL, obviously, but anything else would be nuts.)

Comment: @Bart and how does the "byebye account" solution solve the issue ? He'll create a new one right away, and the underlying issue of having someone under 13 on the network is still here (even though I don't see any issue with it, if he knows how to use SE and doesn't post low quality contributions then it's all good).

Comment: @AndréDaniel: To put it as cynically as possible, **having** someone under 13 on SE isn't an issue, but SE **knowing** that a particular user is under 13 is a major issue.  (I don't think *willful blindness* toward users' ages is excused by the law, but asking for proof-of-age documents would be the only alternative and it's clearly unreasonable.  Again, IANAL.)

Comment: @AndréDaniel it simply doesn't matter. The site is simply required to either not allow such users, or to get into a whole administrative nightmare with explicit parent permissions and the like. If they don't do the latter, they'll have to do the former. If they find an account that explicitly violates that part of the ToS, they'll have to get rid of it if only to avoid the whole danger of "knowlingly/willingly allowing underage users to use the site".

Comment: I'm so glad that I'm just old enough to not get deleted.

Comment: @tmyklebu True, but SO is. You're right about community enforcement; didn't really think my argument through, and now I'm more leaning towards not doing anything, if only slightly. Not sure what to think about this any more.

Comment: Forcing children to lie about their age... such a stupid law.

Comment: @user3580294: I *really* doubt SO is at any risk by having users like me who wouldn't proactively try to find out whether their peers were under 13 so they could report them.  And I *really* *really* doubt I'm at any risk for using SO.

Comment: Regarding moving this to Meta Stack Exchange, this is pretty much [already tagged faq-proposed on there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/how-do-i-use-stack-exchange-if-im-under-13-years-old). I don't know if this really qualifies as a frequently asked question, though. And the FAQ list is bloated enough already.

Comment: @tmyklebu I don't think anyone here is *proactively* looking for ages, it's just more "what do I do when I find out?". And no, you probably aren't at any risk of anything for just using SO, unless the NSA has taken an interest in this site.

Comment: All of the staff/moderators/responsible people are going to follow the letter of the law and tell you to report them, but enforcing the laws on SE is not your responsibility, so you're not required to do anything about

Comment: I think part of the confusion here is people confusing law and SO/SE policy, in no small part due to my wrong comment earlier... I really need to stop saying things before my brain catches up.

Comment: @user3580294 You're not required to police SO/SE policy either

Comment: @SamIam Yep, unless there's some hidden part of the user requirement (which I doubt exists).

Comment: @user3580294: And guess whose responsibility it would be to enforce that part of the agreement?  That's right, it would be SE's!

Comment: @tmyklebu A poorly designed user agreement could always require users to help enforce it... But that part would be impossible to enforce, potentially leading to everyone reporting each other for not reporting violations. Wonderful.

Comment: I'm not here to debate policy, so please allow me to ask the important question. Why do you honestly care? If you have so much time on your hands that you can go around poaching strangers who may or may not be violating TOS, I've got some yard work that needs doing. I promise it will be more rewarding.

Answer (score 30):

Of course this all goes with the general "I am not a lawyer" preface (then why are you talking Bart?) as usual, but here goes:

> What do you do when you find an underage user using the site?

You are **not required to do anything**. It is not a requirement that you as the user enforce [the ToS of the site](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) you're on or the network as a whole. If you hear a user say he's not the mature 13 year old he claims to be by signing up, nothing stops you from shrugging and moving on.

If the user violates the ToS, that's initially simply only the user's problem. If he violates it and makes that publicly known, it could become the site's problem if they then don't act (but they will). But to the best of my knowledge there is no immediate danger for any regular user of the site. They are not a party in all of this.

If you want to report it, you can. You could perhaps flag a contribution where the user states their actual age, though a moderator will have to pass this on to an employee to handle. Or you could use the "contact us" link at the bottom of each page on the network.

The whole debate whether it is fair to only allow users of 13 and older, or whether it helps to nuke the accounts of underage users is besides the point. It's a simple result of [COPPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act) and the options it leaves a site like Stack Exchange. Either you administrate explicit parental consent and the like, or you simply make the site for users of 13 or older only and enforce that to the best of your abilities. It is what it is. And if you don't like it, go and complain to those who made the laws or have the ability to change them.

Comment: If I wrote this, I'd have added something like "if you have nothing better to do than to stop 12-year-olds from learning how to be better programmers, please spend your time on a different site."  Only more offensive.

Comment: We all thank you for not writing this then @tmyklebu ;)

Comment: @tmyklebu to be fair, this particular user I encountered unintentionally vandalized his own question, which is what led me to take a look at his profile in the first place.

Comment: @Cupcake: The problem is that the user is a doofus, right?  I think SO has a bunch of policies and procedures for dealing with doofus beaviour.  And a team of moderators for implementing them.  Why not just alert the mods to the doofus behaviour?

Answer (score 24):

Standard disclaimer: I am not a lawyer. If you're really concerned about anything here, you should consult your own lawyer. (Is this even a legally valid disclaimer? I dunno, because I am not a lawyer.)

As Jon said in his comment, our actions as team members are dictated by the US law [COPPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children's_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act). It applies to everyone on all the sites because Stack Exchange is a US company. When we do get informed of underage users, we have to remove their accounts entirely, so that no personal information is retained.

If you're not an employee of Stack Exchange, nobody is compelling you to report underage users you see. It's like seeing someone jaywalk or litter; you *could* tell a cop, but you don't *have* to. If you decide that you want to, you can e-mail `team@stackexchange.com` with an explanation.

Arguing over whether you *should* do so or not doesn't seem like a productive use of anyone's time to me. Even on this post, it's not really on-topic, just clutter.

Comment: I agree with you up until the last paragraph.  Sticking your nose in others' business isn't a good idea.

Comment: And you're welcome to have that opinion, but this post (and anywhere on the network, really) isn't a great venue for discussing it.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) at the bottom of every page to send a message to the Stack Exchange team. Include the url for the user's profile as well as proof of age.

#### What currently happens to underage user accounts

They're deleted and all personally-identifying information we have about them is removed from SE servers. (Note that this is different from deletion done by moderators. This type requires an employee to push a special red button.)

#### Related

[How long can a temporary suspension be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211217/how-long-can-a-temporary-suspension-be/211220#211220)

Comment: Are they simply deleted though? Moderators can do that. But under 13s go to the SE corporate farm

Comment: The accounts are removed [according to popular demand](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250076/account-suspended-for-1-year-is-this-correct/250079#comment716_250079), @random.

Comment: It sucks to a certain extent - if they are coding at that age and surviving and being a good citizen on SO then more power to them.

Comment: @slugster true, too bad we kind of encourage lying in order for them to survive.

Comment: Anyway, there is a way out by having your parents create the account for you, if you are under 13. I think Doorknob did it, might be good idea to ask him directly and have him explain in more details.

Comment: Unless they are [Community Moderator ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/-1)

Comment: The [Community Moderator ♦](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) is a superbot.  The profile also reveals the undocumented policy that the specific user wouldn't get any badges despite all the numerous edits and votes cast.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Sadly it's not really the SE team's fault. US Law (COPPA) forces this behavior. Most sub-13 year olds know that they just have to lie consistently.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The road to hell is paved with Congressional good intentions.

Comment: -1 Just because there's a bad rule doesn't mean you should participate in enforcing it. You should look the other way and assume the user made a typo entering their age/date-of-birth.

Comment: @random My understanding is that SE has a special delete reason for these that only CMs have access too.

Comment: @R.. Agreed. On the internet, nobody knows if you're a dog. Maybe it's a dog pretending to be a child. Or an adult pretending to be a child. And a child can pretend to be an adult. Just because an age is mentioned doesn't mean it's true or that it makes sense to act on it.

Comment: @R.. if you think the law is wrong you should use your constitutional rights to help change it. In the meantime if you don't follow the law you may incur in legal problems. I may think killing people is OK, and I may do it, but if they catch me, I'll surely be in trouble, as bad as the rule may be. Back to the issue at hand, maybe the parents of the child are of the paranoid type: they find out he made an account without telling them, and decide to sue SE. They are in their right of doing it, as stupid as that may be, but there's no shortage of stupid people in the world.

Comment: @nico: A couple of things:  (1) It's not stupid that people can seek justice from the justice system.  (2) If they sued SE over that, R probably wouldn't be on the hook, so it's still none of his business.  You do not have to help enforce agreements between other people.

Comment: @nico, I don't have any constitutional rights, because I'm not a US citizen. Since I also live nowhere near the US, I don't feel I should bother participating in enforcing US law.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Nobody asks you to enforce US law. I am just saying that SE, which is a US-based company does the right thing when they delete the account following US law. As a non-US user you have every right of not caring about US law and not reporting the profile, that is just up to you, unless otherwise specified in the terms you agree to when registering.

Comment: @Blogbeard: by the way, SE ToS says (bold mine) *Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age. No one under the age of 13 may provide any personal information to or on Stack Exchange (including, for example, a name, address, telephone number or email address). [...] **If You access the Network from outside the United States**, You do so at Your own risk and **You are responsible for compliance with the laws of Your jurisdiction**.*

Comment: @tmyklebu: you misunderstood my comment. My "you" was not addressing R. specifically. It was a generic sentence meaning "if someone reported the profile to SE and they did not do anything about it *because the rule is bad*" they would be infringing the law. Whether you agree or not with the law does not change the law. Again, if you don't care about US legislation, fine, but then don't complain about a company in the US applying US law.

Comment: @Nico I agree that SE have a legal responsibility here. I have none, and other, even US-based, members have none, is all I am saying.

Comment: @nico: Yes, that would be very bad.  SE would probably get sued into oblivion.  Nobody wants that to happen.  My point is that individual contributors have no responsibility to do anything in particular.

Comment: @nico: I took this question to be "I don't like this person and I found out he's violating a stupid rule.  Can I report him for violation of the stupid rule and set an unnecessarily harsh punishment in order?"  To which my reply is "get a hobby."  Lots of people in the comments seemed to be suggesting that, as an individual contributor, one had some sort of duty or responsibility to report people.  One does not.  (You can do whatever you want on the SE network, but your contributions will only be valued if they don't suck.  My stance is that reporting 12-year-olds sucks.)

Comment: @tmyklebu:I think you're over reading the question.  Nowhere the op says he dislikes the kid. He is just in a dilemma on what to do having witnessed something that is against US law and against SE ToS, which he agreed to when signing up to the site. Just so that we are clear, I wouldn't report the profile either, but I would not have any problems if someone did and surely I think SE has to deal with it if it is reported.

Comment: @nico: Maybe.  Going from "a user's profile has the number '11' in it next to the word 'I'm'" to "this person **is** 11 and needs to be taken off the SE network" is a logical leap I'm just not comfortable with people making.  Especially given the situation it puts SE into---they basically *have* to wipe the kids account because of one user's suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't report him.**

He's not doing you any harm, and unless you're an employee of Stack Exchange or a department of the United States justice system, it's none of your business.

Comment: Over/under on how long it takes for SE's legal advisor to memory-hole this post?

Comment: If a co-user is *aware* of a criminal act, and not reporting it, isn't s/he accountable as well?

Comment: @Jongware How is the government going to find you on the other side of the internet, anyway?

Comment: @bjb568: not. As long as I keep my tin foil hat on, hahaha!