# Do we have an age limit for site users?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, users

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44339726/accessing-internet-with-cmd In this question, the asker admits to being 11 years old in broken English (unless I'm misunderstanding the meaning of "have 11 years", which is how you state your age literally in Portuguese).

My question is, does [COPPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act) apply to SE, or do we otherwise have any other imposed age limit on users for the site?

Comment: In that case, the user in the linked question possibly needs to be blocked from stackexchange.

Comment: [How do you report an underage user to Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265891/how-do-you-report-an-underage-user-to-stack-exchange)